# QWidget does not respond after a mouse press event.

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget, qt5

I am trying to get a mouse press event to work with my widget I created but every time I click the widget, the window stops responding and I have to kill the program. Does anyone know how to fix this and also how to get the color to change?

Here is the .h and the .cpp files.

.cpp file:

```
#include "iconwidget.h"
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>

iconWidget::iconWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    this->resize(ICON_WIDGET_WIDTH,ICON_WIDGET_HEIGHT);
    pressed = false;
}

void iconWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QRect areatopaint = event->rect();
    QPainter painter(this);
    QBrush brush(Qt::black);
    QPointF center = this->rect().center();
    QPainterPath icon;
    icon.addEllipse(center,20,20);
    painter.drawPath(icon);
    painter.fillPath(icon, brush);

    if (pressed) {
        brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    }
}

void iconWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = true;
    update();
    iconWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

.h file:

```
#define ICONWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#define ICON_WIDGET_WIDTH 45
#define ICON_WIDGET_HEIGHT 45

class iconWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit iconWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    bool pressed;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // ICONWIDGET_H
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call `mousePressEvent()` in an endless recursion. You should change the line:

```
iconWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
```

in your `mousePressEvent` function to:

```
QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
```

Comment: that worked as far as stopping the window from freezing but the color of the widgets still will not change. any idea why?

Comment: You need to set the brush color before you use it. At the moment it is the last thing you do before exiting paintEvent(). Your change will have no effect.